# Is there anywhere to submit bug reports for Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I can't find a website or any social media accounts (other than the Fallout and Bethesda general accounts). Does anyone know if Bethesda is taking feedback and/or bug reports anywhere official?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can submit a bug report to Bethesda directly. [Here](http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/29960/~/what-can-i-do-if-i-experience-issues-with-fallout-shelter-on-ios-or-android%3F) is their FAQ on what to do if you experience issues.

If you want to submit a question to Bethesda, a direct link to the form is [here](http://help.bethesda.net/app/ask/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDgxMDUyMjMyL3NpZC93RTZqaHQ1bg%3D%3D).

Answer (score 2):

You can post an issue on their support forum. [This page](https://beta-community.bethesda.net/category/60/fallout-shelter-support) has links to the different versions of the game. Follow the link for your platform, and open the stickied link at the top to see what information they're requesting for your post.

It's probably best to search before you post to see if it's already been reported (and see if maybe somebody has come up with a fix).